# How to blacklist filter some lines from logs from Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, logging, application.properties

Is there a way in Spring Boot application.properties file to filter out the extra lines in logs file that I am not interested in like the following:

```
2022-02-14 02:02:02.202 TRACE 22748 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'app.my-key' in PropertySource 'server.ports'
2022-02-14 02:02:02.202 TRACE 22748 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'app.my-key' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties'
2022-02-14 02:02:02.202 TRACE 22748 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'app.my-key' in PropertySource 'servletConfigInitParams'
```

Comment: Disable trace logging for that logger (or disable trace logging in the first place, why is it on?).

Comment: Agree to that. But it is just an example.
My question is that is there a way to filter with Regex or any other way?

Comment: You agree with what? You should disable trace logging for this component (or in its totality in the first place).

Comment: In the question, TRACE logs are the sample ones. So, agree to disabling the TRACE logs. But in case they were some other than TRACE logs logged by the developers, is there any way to blacklist some log lines using the Regex from the application.properties file?

Comment: No. There isn't. My comment doesn't apply to trace alone, you can apply that to other logs as well, disable them for a specific logger. If you want more filter, you will need to write a specific appender/configuration for that. It is not something you can drive from the properties. You can write a filter see https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html